# Magento Layout XML - Block on a page disappeared - Inchoo Featured Products Plugin

Tags: xml, layout, reference, block, magento-1.9

I have an existing Magento template that has been working. Just after what seems to be an unrelated change - A new Category was added - a block of content disappeared. The content is pulled in using the Layout XML for the static page - home.

Here is the XML to add the block - it appears correct:

```
<reference name="featured">
   <block type="featuredproducts/listing"  name="featured_products"
   as="featured_products" template="inchoo/block_featured_products.phtml">
   </block>
</reference>
```

*lines breaks were added for formating

and here is the block_featured_products.phtml that resides in the folder: 
/public_html/app/design/frontend/themename/themename/template/inchoo/

```
<?php 
/**
 *
 * @category   Inchoo
 * @package    Inchoo Featured Products
 * @author     Domagoj Potkoc, Inchoo Team <web@inchoo.net>
 */
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

<div style="float: left;width: 522px;margin: 0 0 7px 0;height: 156px; background: url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/featured_bg.png') ?>) no-repeat;">

    <div class="title_box"><?php echo $this->__('Featured Product') ?></div>

    <?php $i=0;$row=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>

        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 160px; height: 120px;text-align: center;">
            <p class="product-image">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><img class="product-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(120, 90) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <style>
        .regular-price .price {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.price-box {
    background: url("<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/foronly.png') ?>") no-repeat 0 2px;
    padding: 5px 0 10px 90px;
}
.col-3-layout .col-main {
min-height: 0px;
height:462px;
}
</style>
        <div style="float: left; width: 300px; height: 120px;">
                <h5><a style="color: #FFFFFF;display: block;font-size: 18px;padding: 5px 0 0;text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>)"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h5>

                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a style="color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 14px;padding: 0 0 0 8px;text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>)">Get Product Details</a>
        </div>        

        </div>
         <?php 
         break;
         ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Neither of the above had changed prior to the disappearing act.

I have tried to flush the cache, turn off the cache, and have verified the file exists. The theme is also in use - but Firebug shows no trace block_featured_products.phtml file.

Any ideas as to why a category addition would cause this goofiness? Other ideas on troubleshooting?

Magento 1.9.0.1 version and the github for the plugin: https://github.com/buric/Inchoo_FeaturedProducts

The installed plugin doesn't seem to have a version number in the comments - I'll be digging into it most likely

Comment: You should consider contacting Inchoo's support team

Comment: Have you allowed this block "featuredproducts/listing" from admin system => permissions => Blocks. ?

Comment: Suman - that was a great point - but it appears this site needs that patch - 6788. So blocks don't have a whitelist in this version 1.9.0.1. Looks like upgrades are next. Didn't want to start tossing a grenade and a small issue just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer for any one who might find this in the future.

It seems the the Indexes were the issue - adding a new Category messed them up - BUT - Magento never saw it as a problem and did not report the Indexes being out of date and requiring them to be rebuilt.

Steps to fix:
Click on **System** > **Index Management** 
Click **Select All**
[image: Rebuild All the Indexes]

Then at the right change the actions to **Reindex Data** and click **Submit**
[image: Reindex Data Action]

For details on the process see:
https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-issue-a-reindex-in-magento.html

Magento never reported the Indexes were wrong - but this fixed the issue.